# How to run the Java application in Java Embedded version

Tags: java, embedded

I have developed a sample Java application using JDK1.7, compiled the application and generated a Jar file. And now i would like to run the Jar file on Java Embedded version. I have gone through the Oracle official site and downloaded the Java Embedded version 7, but i did not find any tutorial where i can run the Jar file in Embedded version. Iam using Eclipse as an IDE and Windows as a Development environment.Can you please guide me the steps?
Here my Jar file contains only one Class with Main method and just prints "hello Java Embedded version".

Comment: Are we talking about Java SE Embedded here?  Is it (SE) deployed on your target? Is the jar deployed on your target?   Normally one runs java -jar myJarFile.jar.  Have you tried from the command line?  Here is an example of embedded Java on a Beaglebone http://derekmolloy.ie/running-java-applications-on-the-beaglebone-black/

Comment: yes SE deployed on the target. I will check the link which you sent and get back to you if an issues. Thank you very much for you reply